# Linking two Digital Ocean Servers on Cloudways together

Tags: digital-ocean, cloudways

I currently run a Digital Ocean server on Cloudways.

I was wondering what do I do when my server exceeds the highest tier they offer?

Is it possible to do kinda a "load balance" through the API?

I run a pretty massive WordPress multi site with thousands of users.

So for example, my New York DO Server on Cloudways reaches capacity - is it possible to fire up a server in San Francisco and start using that server?

Comment: Currently, clustering is not possible in Cloudways not even with API. I would recommend you to clone your site to Kyup on Cloudways. Kyup is a container-based server. Your server will be auto-scale if it need to consume more resources.

On the other hand you can CDN to minimize server load.

Comment: But isn't the top DO configuration more powerful then the top Kyup configuration?

Comment: If you talking about Cloudways configuration then it would be same for both,